# Random Email Picker of Size n

Tags: python, regex, perl, email

I need `n` random emails from a list of emails much greater than `n`---using Python or Perl. The list of emails is comma delimited like this:

`email1@host.sx, email2@host.sx, ... email100@host.sx`

The file is called `emails.txt`. I just need to find a way to randomly, whatever that happens to mean in this case, select `n` of them out of the list and comma delimit those into a separate file called `email_block.txt`.

---

My understanding of the problem is that I need to REGEX (`\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b`) fetch all the emails into an array and use a random number generator to generate a list of unique numbers between `0` and `x-1`, where `x` is the number of emails in the original list (I'm assuming the beginning array position in Perl and Python starts at `0`), and then use these numbers to print out the new block of emails into another file. Perhaps these random numbers could be put into another array and then be put into the email array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
import csv
import random

def select_n_random(n):
    fin = open('emails.csv', 'rb')
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    email_list = list(reader)[0]
    output_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        idx = random.randint(0, len(email_list)-1)
        output_list.append(email_list.pop(idx))

    fout = open('email_output.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(output_list)

    fout.close()
    fin.close()

select_n_random(10)
```

Edit based on info in comments:

```
import csv
import random

def select_n_random(n):
    fin = open('emails.csv', 'r+')
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    email_list = list(reader)[0]
    output_list = []
    for i in range(n):
        idx = random.randint(0, len(email_list)-1)
        output_list.append(email_list.pop(idx))

    fout = open('email_output.csv', 'wb')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(output_list)

    fout.close()
    fin.close()

    # reopen original file and remove the randomly selected emails
    fin = open('emails.csv', 'w')
    writer = csv.writer(fin, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerow(email_list)
    fin.close()


select_n_random(10)
```

Comment: Personal preference. You can change that to QUOTE_MINIMAL, or QUOTE_NONE if you choose as well. But sometimes special characters throw CSV's for a loop. Now that I'm thinking about it not too many emails have commas in them though...

Comment: It just occurred to me that I need a way to exclude these random emails from the original list...

Comment: @Hipp0 so the original list has to be saved minus the emails we randomly chose?

Comment: Yes, that is right. So, if `email1@host.sx, email2@host.sx, email3@host.sx` is the original list and your program picks `n=2` random emails, say `email1` and `email3`, then I'd need the original to be just `email2@host.sx`, but keep in mind that I've already generated a file with `n` random emails already, and so the elimination will have to be taken from this newly generated file, namely `email_output.csv`.

Comment: I'm going to go get a coffee, be back shortly, and thank you, @tknickman.

Comment: Added another example, hopefully that gives you enough to go on.